Cpanel and Nginx cache problem on specific pages
I use cpanel with nginx cache enabled. When someone open a web page cache works normally.
But I noticed that if the page with a php script only output a short text string (for example it only output "ok"), then that page is cached and the dynamic script no longer run if refreshed.
In this page I already have the php no-cache headers as follows:
header( 'Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' );
header( 'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT' ); 
header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' );
header( 'Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false );
header( 'Pragma: no-cache' ); 

But still, the page is cached and the script no longer run when the page is refreshed, i don't understand why.
How can I disable nginx cache these specific pages?

How short should the string be? What happens with echo time() or echo date("d.m.Y. H:i:s");? Or when you echo $_GET['param'], and then call the script with yourscript.php?param=<whatever_you_want>? Does it reflect the changes in the GET parameter?
